# loop over a nested list dictionary to count key occurrences

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

I am working through a tutorial and couldn't find a answer that works for me for the following problem:
I have a Dictionary nested in a List and want to count the occurrences of a special key, for example "Date" occurs two times:

```
test = [{'Category': 'a', 'Num': '1', 'Day': 'Tuesday', 'Date': '2013'}, {'Category': 'b', 'Num': '1', 'Day': 'Monday', 'Date': '2013'}]
```

As a solution I got:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(item["Date"] for item in test)
print counter
```

That seems to work in the tutorial (though still I don't understand it 100%) but I want to try code it myself. I came up with various solutions but none works my basis was more or less (just to show what I want to do, I know it doesn't work):

```
counter = 0
for x in test:
    if x == "Date":
        counter+=1
print counter
```

Comment: debugging 101: `print x`

Comment: why? I want counter not x?

Comment: have you even tried it?

Comment: yes, x is not a variable why should i print x, there is no x to print?

Comment: o'really? perhaps you need some sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes naming the variable properly will help us understand the problem being solved better.

To check whether a particular key exists in a dictionary, you can use the `in` operator, like this

```
counter = 0
for current_dict in test:
    if "Date" in current_dict:
        counter += 1
print counter
```

You can write the same logic, with list comprehension, like this

```
sum([1 for current_dict in test if "Date" in current_dict])
```

In this code, we are making the loop and the condition flat and the actual value to be generated is 1. If you print this

```
[1 for current_dict in test if "Date" in current_dict]
```

you ll get to see as many `1`s as the number of times `Date` occurs in the list of dictionaries. Then using [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function we are simply adding the entire list.

This can further be shortened. Lets see how to do that. In python, boolean values are actually subclass of integers. So, in Python

```
print True  == 1  # will print True
print False == 0  # will print True
```

We can use this to our advantage, like this

```
sum(["Date" in current_dict for current_dict in test])
```

Here we just removed the `if` condition, instead, for ever dictionary in the list, we are just accumulating a boolean value (an integer). The boolean value will be `True` (1) if `Date` is in the `current_dict`, if it is not there, it will give `False` (0). You can confirm that by just printing

```
print ["Date" in current_dict for current_dict in test]
```

You will get a series of 0's and 1's. We are simply adding them together with `sum` to get the result.

Comment: `sum("Date" in d for d in list_of_dicts)`

Comment: Since the question has "count the occurrences of a special key" I suggest `sum("Date" in d.keys() for d in test)`

Comment: @SvenMarnach Since he is a beginner, I stopped at the LC level itself.

Comment: @embert Nope. Sven's method is better.

Comment: Fair enough, nice explanation.  Just wanted to mention the more concise form.

Comment: @thefourtheye So `in` will check only keys anyway?

Comment: @embert `keys()` is surplus, a `dict` is already a container of its keys.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Please check now :) I included explanation for that case as well. Now, thinking about explaining a little about generator expression. :)

Comment: @embert `d.keys()` will return a list. Member existence checks in a list is `O(N)`, but `"mem" in d` is `O(1)`. So, Sven's method is better.

Comment: @thefourtheye Since we are on it: What does `in` do / call / check?

Comment: @embert `in` will just do a member existence check. It will return `True` if the expression to the left of `in` is found in the object to its right. It can be used in `set`, `dict`, `list`, `tuple` and `string`. In strings, you can use that to check if it is a substring or not. :)

Comment: thanks a lot, great answer and discussion (although I ran into new problems :-))!